# Where does sencha 3.4 actually build the html structure?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm new to javascript and sencha.
I'm looking at the source code of sencha 3.4 and would like to know  where is the actual html structure is built ( for learning purposes )

Names of scripts and line numbers would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the [`Component.render`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-render) ([source](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Component.html#Ext-Component-method-render)) method. From the documentation:

> Render this Component into the passed HTML element.

Usually, this method is called from the parent container's layout. The method uses the combination of component fields (`el`, `html`, `contentEl`, `tpl`, etc.) to generate the HTML element.

Actual DOM manipulation happens further down the line, in utility classes ([`DomHelper`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper)) and in the `onRender` method, which is usually overridden in descendant classes (see [`Label`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Label.html#Ext-form-Label-cfg-forId) for a simple example). Anyway, `render` is a good starting point.